# Is saving images using Amazon S3 the most scalable solution today?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, storage

I'm wondering if storing images using Amazon S3 is the most scalable solution today?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on how much and what kind of traffic you have. I've found S3 to be fairly cheap and easy to use. You might also consider using an Akamai-backed CDN.

Again, impossible to know without some idea of what you're doing.